# Sonar build is failing by showing on project xxxxx: sonar.profile was set to 'YYYY' but didn't match any profile for any language

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am getting the following error while running **mvn sonar:sonar**

```
**Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project xxxxx: sonar.profile was set to 'YYYY' but didn't match any profile for any language. Please check your configuration.**



sonar-project.properties file is : -
----------------------------------------------
# ---- Project metadata
sonar.projectKey=a.b.c.d.play
sonar.projectName=abc
sonar.projectDescription=abc
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# ---- Default settings
sonar.profile=project_abc

# ---- Code coverage..

#Tells SonarQube to reuse existing reports for unit tests execution and coverage reports
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports

#Tells SonarQube where the unit tests execution reports are
sonar.surefire.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports

#Tells SonarQube that the code coverage tool by unit tests is JaCoCo
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=cobertura

#Tells SonarQube where the unit tests code coverage report is
sonar.cobertura.reportPath=test-result/code-coverage/coverage.xml

# ---- Module definitions 
sonar.modules=play_java,play_web,play_js,play_groovy

play_java.sonar.projectBaseDir=a/b
play_java.sonar.sonar.language=java
play_java.sonar.sources=app
play_java.sonar.binaries=precompiled
play_java.sonar.exclusions=**/*.html
play_java.sonar.cobertura.reportPath=test-result/code-coverage/coverage.xml
play_java.sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
play_java.sonar.java.coveragePlugin=cobertura


play_web.sonar.projectBaseDir=a/b
play_web.sonar.language=web
play_web.sonar.sources=app

play_js.sonar.projectBaseDir=a/b
play_js.sonar.language=js
play_js.sonar.sources=assets/javascripts
play_js.sonar.binaries=precompiled
play_js.sonar.exclusions=test/lib/*,test/JasmineConfigure.js,test/*.test.js,test/fixtures/*,thirdparty/**/*.js,thirdparty/*

play_groovy.sonar.projectBaseDir=a/b
play_groovy.sonar.language=grvy
play_groovy.sonar.sources=app
```

I am running sonar for the main project which holds multiple sub projects.
Do I need to change this property file ? I have referred many links. But still getting the error. 
Is it depends on the maven plugin ? 
I am using **maven 3.0.2** and **sonarqube 5.2**

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`sonar.profile` has been deprecated since SonarQube 4.5, which was released in late 2014. I.E. it has been deprecated for a *long time*.

Your use of `sonar.profile` tells the analyzer to use the rule set named `project_abc`. You should remove this setting and let the default profile be applied. If you *really* don't want the default profile, then you should use the SonarQube UI to explicitly assign the project to the profile you do want used.